# I am facing problem to retrive data from list from Realtime database after applying Limit

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to learn Chat app in flutter. For this I was retrieving list of chat from Firebase Real time database. According to my code, when i apply limit like this:

```
_limit = 15;  

final messageRtDatabaseReference =
FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("messages");

StreamBuilder( stream: messageRtDatabaseReference 
.child(widget.groupChatId).limitToLast(_limit).onValue,

builder: (context, dataSnapShot) {
  if (dataSnapShot.hasData) {
    DataSnapshot snapshot = dataSnapShot.data.snapshot;
    Map data = snapshot.value;
    List list = [];
    if (data == null) {
      return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Center(child: Text("")),
      );
    } else {
     data.forEach((index, data) => list.add({"key":index,...data}));            
          list.sort((b, a) {
            return a["timeStamp"].compareTo(b["timeStamp"]);

         })
```

(widget.groupChatId) is pass from different class as parameter, I printed it and it is working fine

My list did not retrieve properly when list objects exceed from 15 as I show in code i set limit to 15. It skip some data from the list. For example if I have 5 messages or five entries in list, so it will show 1st, 3rd, 4th, other 2nd and 5th will be missed. In contrast, when I remove limit like this:

```
StreamBuilder( stream: messageRtDatabaseReference 
.child(widget.groupChatId).onValue,

builder: (context, dataSnapShot) {
  if (dataSnapShot.hasData) {
    DataSnapshot snapshot = dataSnapShot.data.snapshot;
    Map data = snapshot.value;
    List list = [];
    if (data == null) {
      return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Center(child: Text("")),
      );
    } else {
          
    data.forEach((index, data) => list.add({"key": index,...data}));           
          list.sort((b, a) {
            return a["timeStamp"].compareTo(b["timeStamp"]);

         })
```

All the list load accurately without missing any slot.

Database Image:

[image: Link of Database image]

Any one knew why is that? I am trying for like 5 hours but did not get the solution. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for adding the code, and the picture of the database. Going forward, please don't delete your [existing post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68748832) after getting feedback, but instead address the feedback in that post by clicking the `edit` link right under it.

Comment: I made your image visible, but in the future (as said in my comment on your deleted question) consider showing the database as text instead of a screenshot. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Thank you sir, :), I will remember for next time

Comment: Can you also edit your question to show how `messageRtDatabaseReference` and `widget.groupChatId` are initialized? Keep in mind: if you don't show it to use, we can't see it.

Comment: I just edit it, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to be certain without seeing your actual data, but I think you might be getting the "wrong" results because you're not specifying what to order the data on in:

```
StreamBuilder( stream: messageRtDatabaseReference 
.child(widget.groupChatId).limitToLast(_limit).onValue,
```

Since you're reordering on `timeStamp`, you'll actually want to order the query on that:

```
StreamBuilder( stream: messageRtDatabaseReference 
.child(widget.groupChatId).orderByChild("timeStamp".limitToLast(_limit).onValue,
```

---

Ideally you shouldn't have to re-order the results in your code, since Firebase already returns them in the correct order this way. But when you convert the messages into a map with `Map data = snapshot.value` all information about the order it lost.

You'll want to get the results from the snapshot in the correct order with `snapshot.value.values` (if I recall correctly).

Comment: Dear Sir, This solution is working fine. I am very thankful to you. You save my I don't know how many days :)

Comment: Yes sir, I was finding some button to vote you. But unfortunately my profile does not support it yet. I will be follow your link and will up-vote when this option available for me .. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use orderbychild keyname.
messageRtDatabaseReference .child(widget.groupChatId).orderByChild(“name”).limitToLast(_limit).onValue